# Map a list of Python Dictionaries to a Matlab struct

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, struct, mapping

I am trying to map a list of Python dictionaries to a specific `.mat` fromat. I need to do this because I used Python to develop some code to generate 'paintings' (ie. represented by such a dictionary) but want to re-use a Matlab program provided from another project which visualizes dictionaries of this structure.

Throughout my project I've made sure that all the names, types and structures of the painting I generated match with the example dataset of the Matlab project. The final step is now to convert it to this `.mat` fromat. For this, I am using `numpy` and `scipy.io`. Important to note however is, I have no experience whatsoever with Matlab, which is why I developed my code in Python.

**My Python Dictionary:**

```
[{'xmax': 593, 'ymax': 685, 'h_pts': [0, 168, 362, 685], 'v_pts': [0, 25, 468, 487, 540, 593], 'h_thick': [0, 14, 16, 0], 'v_thick': [0, 14, 15, 16, 17, 0], 'h_ext': [[1, 6], [2, 6], [2, 5], [1, 6]], 'v_ext': [[1, 4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]], 'rect': [[4, 3, 3, 5], [4, 3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5, 6], [4, 1, 1, 2], [3, 2, 4, 5], [3, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 6]], 'rect_colors': [2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]}]
```

**The example representation of the `.mat` file (what I desire):**
[image]

**What I am trying at the moment:**

```
saveformat = {}
paintings = [<python dictionary as above here>, ...]   
representations = np.asarray(representations).astype('object')    
saveformat['reps'] = representations
sio.savemat("cool_name.mat", saveformat)
```

**My result in Matlab:**

[image]

*When clicking on one of the cells above ^*

[image]

Clearly, something goes wrong here, and I can't seem to figure out what exacly from the documentation of `scipy.io`. Instead of generating a column for each key-value of the dictionary and then listing the values for those keys for every dictionary instance in the rows, it simply generates one row with one dictionary in each column (one for each painting).

As such, the question is fairly straight forward, how does one go about mapping this format correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is suboptimal but, have you consider a pandas aproach like this?

```
dict1, dict2 = {'x': 1, 'y': 0, 'h': [1,2]}, {'x': -1, 'y':2, 'h':[3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = dict1.keys(),data = [dict1,dict2])
```

You get

```
 |-------|-------|-------|
 |   x   |   y   |   h   |
 |-------|-------|-------|
 |   1   |   0   | [1,2] |
 |-------|-------|-------|
 |   -1  |   2   | [3,3] |
 |-------|-------|-------|
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not seem to work raising a value error. Is there no good approach to do this using numpy and scipy.io?

Comment: Value error when you try to generate the dataframe or somewhere else?

Comment: It appears on this line: `pd.DataFrame(keys, paintings)` with `keys = paintings[1].keys()` and `paintings`being the list of paintings (the dictionaries): `raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 1), indices imply (5, 1)`

Comment: The first positional arguments in the dataframe call is data, so i would explicit pass them as kwargs, i.e, columns = keys, data = paintings

Comment: No errors come up now, but I get this as a result: https://i.gyazo.com/d99572027c5c1ed93afb229b0b2c869e.png. When you click on the structs, there is no data there.

Comment: First i would check if the dataframe has the right values, and then probably import the df as a csv file, something like `df.to_csv('my_file',index = false)` and finally read the csv on labmat.

Comment: My aim is to directly save it to a .mat file, it's unfortunate I'm just not familiar enough with Matlab and there is such lack of documentation to correctly map this 'easy' problem. Thanks for your help though, I almost thought I had it at first with your solution :p

Comment: One last try. You can get a numpy array with the df values using `numpy_array = df.values` and maybe you can export that.

Comment: But that would still mean I don't directly save my datastructures into a .mat file but need to do some manual exporting/importing, right?

Comment: It seems that there is no direct export from panda to matlab, at least after a quick google search i couldn't find one. It seems that you can do it directly with scipy but i would really do it as a csv, it would save you a lot of work

Comment: I just tried exporting it to a .csv, this is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/241870988964a030f07638794c27a97d.png. It seems like something is wrong there.

Comment: It seems that the separation symbol isn't correctly set. By default the csv exported by pandas is comma separated, and probably that one was read with tab separation

Comment: If I put it to comma, it also tries to seperate the comma's present in the lists. So I don't get h-ext with value [1,2,3,4] but something very werid. I think the right approach is to use the scipy.io library but I need to find someone who understands it better then I do xd

Comment: Oh that's right but you can change the separation symbol in the export with `sep = ;` inside the to_csv call

Comment: I can now succesfully load in the csv file into Matlab, creating a table. However, due to it being a .csv file it loads in as a table instead of a Matlab struct, resulting in the code not working on it :/